# In TLS 1.3, is the Binder Key in a non-PSK derived key schedule always a consistent value?

Tags: tls

The [Key Schedule](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-93) in the [TLS 1.3 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446) starts like this:

```
             0
             |
             v
   PSK ->  HKDF-Extract = Early Secret
             |
             +-----> Derive-Secret(., "ext binder" | "res binder", "")
             |                     = binder_key
             |
             +-----> Derive-Secret(., "c e traffic", ClientHello)
             |                     = client_early_traffic_secret
             |
             +-----> Derive-Secret(., "e exp master", ClientHello)
             |                     = early_exporter_master_secret
            ...
```

[Later in Section 7.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-94), the RFC provides guidance on what to use as a substitute value for PSK if a Pre-Shared-Key is not actually used:

> ```
>    If a given secret is not available, then the 0-value consisting of a
>    string of Hash.length bytes set to zeros is used.  Note that this
>    does not mean skipping rounds, so if PSK is not in use, Early Secret
>    will still be HKDF-Extract(0, 0).
> ```

The `client_early_traffic_secret` and `early_exporter_master_secret` include a transcript hash of the Client Hello, which includes a Random Number generated by the client. So these two keys will be different for every SSL Session.

However, the `binder_key` does not include any transcript hash. Which means *(by my interpretation)*, the only values feeding into the `binder_key` secret are both **known by everyone** and **never change** (0 as the starting value, 000...0 as the substitute for PSK, and the constant labels `ext binder` or `res binder`).

Am I interpreting that correctly? If so, how is this not a reduction in security that one of the output secret keys of the key schedule never changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binder key is used only for the [PSK binder](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2.11.2), which

> forms a binding between a PSK and the current handshake, as well as between the session where the PSK was established and the current session.

Without a previous session to establish a PSK, there's nothing to bind. There's no PSK to bind to the current handshake, and there's no previous session where the PSK was established. So the binder key *is* constant when not using a PSK, since it's only used to ensure that the client knows the same PSK that the server stored.